# Custom C# Webserver cannot accept simultaneous ajax calls

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, sockets

I have written a custom web server for a web application I am developing, however, I am stumped on a weird problem I seem to be having with .NET sockets.

For webpages the server works completely fine but when making an ajax call to the server to perform a function that has a lengthy processing time, the server is unable to accept another ajax call from the same session.

The process is as such:

A button press on the website causes an ajax call to http://localhost:900/function:index (My server recognizes this) which performs an lengthy operation returning "success" when it finishes.

If I push the button again before the initial call returns, the browser makes the same call to the server but this time, Socket.Accept() does not return a new socket and there is no indication that there is a connection waiting. (Firebug does show a connection attempt though)

However, if I refresh the page or click a link to load a new page, it works as expected and the button works as expected (returning a fail as the operation is still continuing)

To sum it up: Socket.Accept() does not return a new socket if an existing, identical ajax call is still processing.

I am stumped... Any ideas as to why this may be?

Comment: Are you creating a thread pool?

Comment: I am using the thread pool yes, but not until the server actually accepts the connection, so the thread pool doesn't even come into play yet.

Comment: It sounds as if your threading model is not set up correctly, though I must confess I have not tried to write a custom listener like that before.  Why would you not use IIS for this?  It's designed specifically for this type of thing.

Comment: How are you creating the Socket? Are you using `System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener`?

Comment: Jeremy: The server is meant to be run 24/7 on an users machine in which they can access the web interface as a means to control it. A typical users machine would likely not have IIS and I needed some features which are rather unique.

I had figured it was my threading model at first, but I rearranged it so it only launches a new thread after the socket accepts the connection. Since the connection never comes, threading doesn't come into play yet.

Comment: sblom: I'm just using the regular Socket class.

Comment: @JoshMackey  Are you doing this just as a learning exercise?  HttpListener, Kayak and Firefly all do what you seem to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appears that the answer lay in the browser. By adding an arbitrary time argument onto the end of the url so that every request was unique, it worked.

For whatever reason, the browser would not send two simultaneous ajax calls at once.

Comment: Could be the browser thought it could go off of a cached result, and thus only actually talked to the server once.  Perhaps you could add in an "expires" header? *shrug*

Comment: That is a thought, but then why would it work again as soon as the first call returns?